# What causes banding in CSS box-shadows and how to prevent it?

Tags: css, google-chrome, colors, shadow

Specifically we see this issue in Google Chrome.

The relevant CSS is: `box-shadow: rgb(67 66 66) 0px 0px 0px 1px, rgb(18 18 18) 0px 0.125rem 0.75rem, rgb(18 18 18) 0px 0.5rem 2.5rem;`

Here's the issue with the contrast boosted in case it might not be visible on everyone's monitor (see below for original):

[image]

**The original:**

[image]

What causes this? Can it be prevented?

Comment: It is essentially not the HTML/CSS not being able to display the colors properly, but a combination of browser graphic routines, PC graphics drivers and the maximum number of color variations needed to get a *smooth* transition between two colors over a given distance. You see this in photogaphy as well. from `1px` up to `2.5rem` there is more space than color tones available to smoothen things out. Also `rgb(18 18 18)` is a full greytone while `rgb(67 66 66)` is just slightly more red than a proper grey scale. Try using full greyscle tones in this case. Try subtle differences and use HSL.

Comment: Thanks for this - very informative! Unfortunately full greytone colors didn't make a difference. What's the benefit of using HSL in this context? The colors are programmatically generated, so seemingly simple tweaks might not be simple, but I'm open to doing what we have to to prevent this, if we can. I'm guessing the only real workaround here is likely to be reducing the blur amount of our shadow? Thanks again!

Comment: E.g. your `rgb(67 66 66)` is `hsl(0, 0.8%, 26.1%)`. All you have to do is fiddle with the lightness parameter to finetune the darkness of the color, instead of coming up with 3 RGB values. Admitted, with greyscales those values would be equal. However in this case, you would need to check if the redness is still the same, with HSL the H and S parameter take care of that. FYI,  H = 0 => 'red' (top of the color wheel), S = 0.8% => 'very dull', L = 26.1% => 'very little light'. Understanding CSS `hsl(..)` will be well worth your time digging in to, regardless of your current issue.

Comment: Here is a link to a small tut on Codepen I created some time ago showing how easy it is to manipulate color wheel harmonies by simply changing HSL parameters in CSS. In this case the four color 'tertiary color harmony' of a predefined color `hsl(215, 20%, 50%)`, a dull blue. [Codepen: HSL tertiary colors with CSS vars](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/zYpGwYo?editors=0100)

Comment: Okay, revisiting the page myself I discovered a few stupid mistakes that needed correction. So the pen is now called [Codepen: HSL tetradic colors with CSS vars](https://codepen.io/renevanderlende/pen/zYpGwYo). No biggy, but it needed a few changes... Sorry for that!